# UIView animation not smooth, jerky on repeat

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

I'm trying to create a rotating-wheel animation and while it's working, the animation seems really jerky. I need to rotate this wheel indefinitely and stop it based on user interaction. The code I've used is given below.

```
-(void) spinWheel{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 delay:0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
        _wheel.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(_wheel.transform, _rotationVelocity*ONE_SECTION_ROTATION);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if(finished){
            if(!_decelerating){
                [self spinWheel];
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

Now. however, due to the high speed of the spinning of the wheel, there's a jerk noticed when the animation cycle finishes, before the recursive call to restart the animation.

I'm not sure how I would implement something like this to run smoothly.

**EDIT:** To make things more obvious, _decelerating is ALWAYS false. It is meant to turn _true when a user taps a button, but I have not programmed that in yet. So, the recursive call is always made for now.

Comment: try beginfromcurrentstate flag

Comment: @Andy, doesn't make a difference. 
Don't know why it should because the previous animation completes before the new one starts. My problem is that the animation stops and restarts (like it should) but it's noticeable. The user can see it stop for a fraction of a second and restart. Looks jerky. So I need a smoother way of animating this wheel

Comment: I suppose it removes presentation before running next animation which reverses transform back to original value.. Answer below suggests the use of CABasicAnimation which should be sufficient enough.

Comment: @Andy CABasicAnimation didn't work either. I've left a comment explaining the issue.

Comment: _rotationVelocity = 1
ONE_SECTION_ROTATION = M_PI/5
_decelerating is a flag that is set to false. It is set to true when a user taps a button.

Comment: Can you please post your solution? I just came across this same problem, and couldn't solve it so far. Thanks!

Comment: @RoiMulia posted my solution as an answer, along with my code.

Comment: @sosale151 , Thank you! Much appreicated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this problem, I used a CABasicAnimation as suggested by vats. I set a fromValue of 0, toValue of one complete rotation, repeatCount of INFINITY, and duration to be equal to the time necessary to complete one rotation.

This allowed me to infinitely rotate the wheel. When I needed it to stop based on the user interaction, I then removed the above animation, calculated the current position of the wheel and replaced with a second animation responsible for deceleration. This second animation was a CAKeyframeAnimation with multiple distinct keyTimes and values based on the speed of deceleration I wanted to set. I've released the code as a gist on github, it's a little messy because a lot of the variable names are specific to my program. But it could give you an idea on how I solved it.

https://gist.github.com/sosale151/454baadd2634590bffbf11a5077b8a7c

Answer (score 1):

With any Transformation(Scaling, rotation, and translation ) it is best considered to use `CABasicAnimation` instead of `UIView animation`.

To answer why:

All I know is Quartz provides functions to create and transform objects so that is why `CABasicAnimation`(Core animation) is worth the deal.

Comment: It didn't remove the jerkiness. I need the wheel to rotate indefinitely and stop based on a certain user interaction. I got the view to rotate indefinitely by using spinWheelAnimation.repeatCount = INFINITY; However, the problems with this are
1) When the animation is removed when the user interaction happens, the position of the actual view is reset to what it originally was.
2) If I remove the repeatCount = INFINITY and set it to 1, and recursively call the method, the jerk is still noticed.

Comment: If there is a way to complete the current cycle of the animation before it stops, I might be able to solve the problem. But I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Took your advice, did some reading and found a fix building upon CABasicAnimation. Thanks loads!

Comment: Your answer didn't completely fix my problem, but it gave me a foundation to build my own solution. Hence I've given you an up vote.

Comment: @sosale151 Can you please post your solution? I just came across this same problem, and couldn't solve it so far. Thanks!

Comment: @RoiMulia Try using QoS services with "User-interaction" enum. They emerged with powerful solutions.

Comment: Hey @vats , even if I'm prioritizing, the animation it self will be performed with what code? I mean, I still cant get ot smooth

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 -(void) spinWheel {
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.30 animations:^{
_wheel.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(_wheel.transform, _rotationVelocity*ONE_SECTION_ROTATION);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    if(finished){
        if(!_decelerating){
            [self spinWheel];
        }
    }
}];
}
```